# How do I install Ubuntu 20.04 with old/non EFI BIOS?

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, system-installation

I have been an Ubuntu user for 20 years and never really had a problem. But I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 server on a mature server and I can't get it to boot. I've tried 3 different times, and it never boots after removing the install disk. It took me a while to figure out how to set up RAID with the new partioner (yuck, "reformat" to delete partitions?) but as far as I know everything looks good. The install seems to proceed normally, but it boots to a blank screen with a blinking server. This is an old server without EFI but the only option in the installer seems to be to use GPT partitions. I just installed 18.04 to see if I was crazy and it installs an boots normally. My current plan is to just upgrade the virgin 18.04 to 20.04 but surely there is a better way?

Comment: I QA-test Ubuntu (and *flavor*) desktop and use devices as old as from 2004, so I'm using BIOS only (pre-uEFI boxes) and have no issues. You weren't specific as to which ISO you tried, and thus which installer? (were you trying with a `subiquity` ISO? or which? did you try network installer? (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso) or which ISO or ISOs and specific release (20.04? 20.04.1? 20.04.2?)

Comment: If you want to install in BIOS mode on a GPT drive you need a small (~1MB) unformatted "bios_grub" partition.

Comment: @James B, thank you so much for posting AND answering this question. This saved me a lot of time after I already wasted a lot of time on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I did not create any bios_grub partitions, so that might be it. But I never had to before and you would think the partitioner would warn you about that, like it should warn you that you don't have a partition designated as root.

But it seems that is par for the course for the partitioner. It provides an option to delete partition and then gives you an error when choosing it. It's also annoying to be required to use GPT partitions. Plus on the third install attempt I noticed one of the drives (seemingly at random) offered an option to make it "bootable", but it didn't seem to have any effect. I'm incredibly underwhelmed with the partitioner in general so hopefully it will be improved by 22.04 when I probably won't have any choice but to use it. Also, I don't know how long I waited on the process to finish the first time before I noticed that a tiny "Reboot" option had appeared at the bottom. No message or log item stating it was done or it was OK to reboot, nothing.

However, it turns out that there is an Ubuntu 20.4 "legacy server install" ISO, which solved my problem. The URL is "http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/". I had zero problems using that ISO and it was a pleasure to use.

Comment: Oh, and I was using the standard ISO downloaded from an official mirror, using RAID1 on two small SSDs for the system and also RAID1 on two 3TB drives for storage. The server is an old SuperMIcro 1U server with Phoenix BIOS circa 2008. It's got 8 intel cores running at 3Ghz, so it's a shame it's so hard to install Ubuntu on it now.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this post. Pointing out the legacy ISO not only fixed my issue I was about to waste even more time on this issue. I understand your frustration and I cannot believe this isn't a normal option in the modern installer of Ubuntu 20. https://superuser.com/a/1683387/620290